# Speeding up scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I wonder whether someone would be so kind and suggest improvement where possible:

```
ContactAuto2 <- function(x) {
                tryCatch({
        tabs <- getURL(paste("http://google.de/",x,sep=""))
     xmltext <- htmlParse(tabs,encoding = "UTF-8", asText=TRUE)
    xmltable <- xpathApply(xmltext, "//adresse/text()[preceding-sibling::br]",xmlValue)
         val <- gsub("\r\n","",xmltable)
        val2 <- gsub("(\\D)([0-9])","\\1 \\2",val)
    FinalValue <- str_trim(val2)
        }, error=function(e) cat())
     }


   Base <- lapply(url1, ContactAuto2)
```

If I use `sapply(url1, ContactAuto2)` there is speed improvement but the data layout is not good.

Is there a way to improve the speed here? Why is `lapply` so slow compared to `sapply`?

I would like you to just glance through and make suggestion if any since there is no real workable full example.

Comment: I suggest you to pose this type of question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because it concerns more code improvement ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, read `?Rprof`.  It's a speed profiler, and will give you a table of the run-times of every individual execution in your function, making it easy to see where the speed issues are.

Here's one (my first) suggestion.

```
tabs <- getURL(paste("http://google.de/",x,sep=""))
```

Google is a massive search engine, and depending on what you're searching for, "Googling" every iteration may suck up a lot of time.  Additionally, you're nesting `paste` in a function that downloads information.  While it may not in your function, nesting function calls almost always slows things down.  Consider pasting  before calling `getURL`.  Also, I would use `paste0` instead of `paste` in this situation.

```
system.time(replicate(1e6, paste('a', 'b', sep = '')))
## user  system elapsed 
## 5.864   0.000   5.679 
system.time(replicate(1e6, paste0('a', 'b')))
## user  system elapsed 
## 3.98    0.00    3.82
```

I can't go much further than that without knowing what the `xmltable`s look like.  Can you please provide a few sample URLs for us to test your function on?